# Bash script 'if' statement that calls a function with parameters

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want an if statement in my bash script that does:

```
if [[ "$v" == "A" || my_func $x $y ]] ; then
```

but I get the error "conditional binary operator expected".
I've tried putting quotes round the parameters in the call to my_func, but still no good. Tried playing around with eval, which didn't help either.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `[[ ]]` is not part of if syntax; `if` takes a command, and `[[` happens to be a builtin which can act as a comand, but not all things passed to `if` need to be within `[[ ]]` -- only tests and non-numeric comparisons (numeric comparisons should use `(( ))`).

Comment: I don't understand why you are using [[ instead of [ here.  You can simply do: if [ "$v" = A ] || my_func $x $y; then ...  or even 'test $v = A || my_func $x $y && ...'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try:

```
if [[ "$v" == "A" ]] || my_func $x $y ; then
```